# recent keystrokes visible on shutdown

Tags: 12.10, gnome, logout

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 and use the Gnome 3 Shell.
The problem is the following:

If I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> during shutdown to show the shutdown messages instead of the splashscreen, sometimes it shows me all of the keystrokes I recently entered anywhere, be that website search forms, written mails, or `sudo` password prompts.
I cannot imagine that this is working as intended.

I noticed this when I shut down my computer using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>, after I experienced some screen tearing and the shutdown menu option was mysteriously missing (So there definitely is something else (at least at times) wrong)

I am using the AMD catalyst fglrx-legacy drivers provided by [this](https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx) repository, because my graphics card is no longer supported by the fglrx driver.

I tried searching for people with a similar problem, but I can't for the life of me come up with a query that finds me anything useful.

Is this a known issue?
Did I somehow install a keylogger from a 3rd party repo?

I will try to add a picture later today, but basically what you see on screen is a whatever I typed before, with a bunch of control characters thrown in `^[[....`

Comment: Can you upload a picture of the problem? What graphics drivers did you install?